# Nodejs decoding and encoding images

Tags: node.js, fs, multer

I think i am doing something wrong when uploading and downloading images.
Images are roughly around 1 mb.

Problem:

Getting images from mongodb takes around 10 minutes and my image data array when logged is between 800k - 1.2 mil.

```
itemImage:
contentType: "image/jpeg"
data: {type: "Buffer", data: Array(911067)}
```

Code Below:

Nodejs:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: (err, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.filename + "-" + Date.now());
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});


route.post("/item", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  const owner = req.body.owner;

  
    const imagePath = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    const enc_img = imagePath.toString("binary");

    // console.log(req.file)
    const a =
      itemImage: {
        data: new Buffer.from(enc_img, "binary"),
        contentType: req.file.mimetype,
      },
    };

    store
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { storeOwner: owner },
        {
          $push: {
            storeItem: a,
          },
        }
      )
      .then(() => {
        res.json({ message: "Item Added." });
      });
  
});



route.get('/image/:user',(req,res)=>{
const identifier = req.params.user

store
    .findOne({storeOwner:owner})
    .then((response)=>{
        res.json()
    })
}
```

Comment: You need not have to store your complete image in the database, rather you should only store its name or its entire location & use this info whenever you want to access the image.

Comment: how would i go about doing this?

Comment: you can use aws s3 bucket to store your images and whenever you upload your image in s3 you will in return get the url of that image. Finally you can store that url in your db instead of the actual raw image. note: this is just one of the many ways of doing this.

Comment: is it possible to only use mongodb to store and retrieve data?

Comment: are you using mongodb locally or using mongodb atlas?

Comment: i'm using mongodb atlas